# SearchView + Filterable RecyclerView make SearchView losing focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have both `searchView` and `recyclerView` in same layout. 
`recyclerView` is using filter and it's working properly.

The problem occurred when i entered query on `searchView`. Instead of let me finish typing, `searchView` will lose focus after i entered first character of my query. Let's say i want show all items which contain "1234" in its name, `searchView` will lose focus after i entered "1" then display all items which contain "1". I have to click that `searchView` again if i want to continue.

Here is my layout (in fragment):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/sv_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:queryHint="Hint"
            app:theme="@style/AppSearchView">

        </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider50"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/light_grey"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my filter command:

```
private void setSearchview() {
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

I have similar layout in custom alert dialog and it's working fine without any issues. Weird right?

Comment: return true instead of false

Comment: @ChandraShekharKaushik Hello, i have tried this but looks like the problem is item inside my recyclerView keep stealing the focus. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a focusable item (like an EditText) inside your RecyclerView, it might be stealing the focus on the first update.
To disable the RecyclerView gaining any focus, you can add the `descendantFocusability` parameter to the XML like this:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If you need to focus inside the RecyclerView, you might work out a solution which sets this parameter dynamically (so it turns focus off before the update, and back on after it).

Answer (score 0):

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
       adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
       return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
       adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
       return true;
     }
});
```

change false to true.

Comment: Hello, i have tried this but looks like the problem is item inside my recyclerView keep stealing the focus. Thank you anyway.